# P and O visas for performers

Tags: visa, working-visas, immigration, canadian-citizens

I am a circus artist from Canada and I currently have a P1 visa, where I perform in the USA as part of a performance team. I am applying for an O-1B visa because I have been offered another employment opportunity, as an individual performer, with a separate company. I know I can have a P and O visa at same time but **can I be working for separate companies under each visa at same time while I am in the USA**? I heard I can only work for one company at a time since they require different visas.

The work/performances I do under the P1 visa is only part time and so I have lots of time off throughout the week to be working elsewhere. I want to make the most of my time here in the USA and so would like to be working/performing with both companies at same time. 
Thanks so much for any insight.